# Unable to do WinRM from Domain machine to Standalone machine (both are Azure VM)

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, winrm

I am trying to do WINRM on standalone machine from Devops pipeline agent machine. Both machines are part of our network and both are Azure VM.

Analysis/ activities so far:

I have domain user access on agent machine

I have Local admin user on standalone machine

WinRM service under Services shows Running on both machine.

Added  standalone private ip on agent machine TrustedHosts

Already executed EnablePSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck  command on both machines

executed netstat -ab  on standalone machine and  it shows 5985 port listening, 5986 is not in this list

```
$username='myUserName'
$password='myPassword'
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $secpasswd)
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $name -Port 5985 -Credential $credentials
```

username/ password in this code is local admin user cred of standalone machine.

Still failed to connect.

Answer (score 2):

•   I would suggest you to please check whether the below group policy settings are configured correctly on the domain machine and the standalone VM. On the domain group policy server, go to all the GPOs and check whether the below settings are configured or not: -

```
 Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Remote Management -> WinRM Client -> Allow Basic authentication -> Enabled; Allow CredSSP authentication -> Enabled; Allow Unencrypted traffic -> Enabled; WinRM Service -> Allow Remote Server Management through WinRM -> Enabled; Allow Basic authentication -> Enabled; Allow CredSSP authentication -> Enabled; Allow Unencrypted traffic -> Enabled; Turn On Compatibility HTTPS Listener -> Enabled ‘
```

Similarly, as above, in the same path, go to **Windows Remote Shell -> Allow Remote Shell Access -> Enabled**. Once these group policy settings are enabled on both the domain Group policy server as well as the standalone Azure VM, the **WinRM connection** should happen successfully. Also, ensure to enable these settings in local group policy on the domain joined Azure VM and the standalone Azure VM too.

•   Once the above has been done, ensure that the commands below are executed in command prompt on the standalone Azure VM and the Devops pipeline agent machine also. The commands will locate the WinRM listener and the addresses. Also, the subsequent commands will configure the WinRM service with default settings: -

```
     winrm e winrm/config/listener 
     winrm get winrm/config
     winrm quickconfig -> Y
```

The output of the above last command will be as follows: -

```
  WinRM has been updated for remote management.

  WinRM service type changed to delayed auto start.
  WinRM service started.
  Created a WinRM listener on https://* to accept WS-Man requests to any IP on this machine. ‘
```

The above commands should be executed in elevated privileges command prompt only. Also, along with that, ensure that the **HTTPS port 5986** for WinRM is open from both ends to ensure HTTPS traffic. For more information, please refer to the below link for more details: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management